# Saving a highlighted button on different View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, highlight

I have already coded my buttons on my app (calendar) to be highlighted. However, when I go to a different view controller it won't save what I have highlighted. Do I need to coded a DestViewController or something else for the highlighted buttons to be saved when I choose to go back to the previous view controller? I am using the language Swift and I am in a Single-App View Application.[Main View Controller, when the user presses PICK DAYS it goes to the January](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBraK.png) [January View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAGRc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could save an array of the previously highlighted buttons and set the highlighted values to true in `viewWillAppear`

**example**

```
class CalenderViewController: UIViewController{
    var highlightedBtns = [UIButton]()
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        highlightBtns()
    }

    func highlightBtns(){
        if highlightedBtns.count > 0{
            for btn in highlightedBtns{
                btn.highlighted = true
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func calenderBtn(sender: UIButton){
        highlightedBtns.append(sender)
        //other actions
    }
}
```